# Replace repeating Dataframe values in R conditionally

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this.

```
test <- data.frame(data=c("one", "two", "three12, threa12", "four", "five"))
```

I need a solution that will find any cell that is comma separated and repeating and replace with just what's on the LHS of the comma....ie make the 3rd cell simply just say three12.

Any help would be appreciated.
Paul.

Comment: Try `sub(",.*$", "", test$data)`.

Comment: In your example, the comma separated value doesn't repeat. Is this a typo? (three12 is not the same as threa12) If you genuinely only want repeats removed you need to use back references, such as `sub("^(.*), \\1$", "\\1", test$data)`, otherwise anything after any comma will be removed, as in @RuiBarradas suggestion - but perhaps that's what you meant?